# Loading speed issue with screen flow

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I designed a screen flow that I hosted on a Salesforce site. The flow is called through a Visualforce page and I used a lightning component for the lightning runtime.
This is how it looks like on the page:
[image]

However, I noticed that the starting screen of the flow (the white box in the middle of the page) takes quite some time to load, leaving the page empty for a while.

[image]

Is there a way in the code to speed up the flow loading?

This is my VF page:

```
    <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
   <html>
      <head>

         <apex:includeLightning />   

         <style type="text/css">


        html { 
           background: url('{!$Resource.TKTbg}') no-repeat center center fixed; 
           -webkit-background-size: cover;
           -moz-background-size: cover;
           -o-background-size: cover;
           background-size: cover;
           height: 100%;
           overflow: hidden;
         }

        .flow {
            width: 700px;
            height: auto;
            max-height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            opacity: 0.9;
            overflow: auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.77); 
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 16px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.77);
        }

        input {         
            /*height: 9px !important;*/
            padding: 6px 6px !important;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            /*display: block !important; */
            font-size: 12px !important;
            line-height: 16px !important;
            color: #191919 !important;
            background-color: #efefef !important;
            border: 1px solid #009ee8 !important;
            border-radius: 4px  !important;
            width: 9cm;
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-input {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border: 1px solid rgb(217, 219, 221);
            border-radius: .25rem;
            width: 4.4cm;
            transition: border .1s linear,background-color .1s linear;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0 1rem 0 .75rem;
            line-height: 1.875rem;
            min-height: calc(1.875rem + (1px * 2));
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-form-element__label {
            color: black;
            font-size: 14px;
      }

      .flowruntime-input-label[flowruntime-inputWrapper2_inputWrapper2] {
            font-weight: 400;
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-input-has-icon_right .slds-input__icon, .slds-scope .slds-input-has-icon--right .slds-input__icon {
            right: auto;
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-button_brand, .slds-scope .slds-button--brand {
            background-color: #f158b2;
            border-color: #ffffff;
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-button_neutral, .slds-scope .slds-button--neutral {
            background-color: #969596;
            border-color: #ffffff; 
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-button_brand:hover, .slds-scope .slds-button_brand:focus, .slds-scope .slds-button--brand:hover, .slds-scope .slds-button--brand:focus {
            background-color: #303030;
            border-color: #303030;
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-button_neutral:hover, .slds-scope .slds-button_neutral:focus, .slds-scope .slds-button--neutral:hover, .slds-scope .slds-button--neutral:focus {
            background-color: #303030;
            border-color: #303030;
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-button:hover, .slds-scope .slds-button:focus {
            color: white;
      }

      .slds-scope .slds-button {
         color: white;
      }

      .slds-scope {
            color: #333;
      }

      .flowruntimeInputWrapper .required {
         margin: 0 .325rem;
      }

      .slds-scope a {
         text-decoration: underline;
         color: #005fb2;
      }

      select {
            color: #000;
            height: 0.8cm;
            width: 9cm;
            border-radius: 5px;
      }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="slds-scope" >
         <div id="flowContainer" class="flow" style="background-color:white">
            <script>
               var statusChange = function (event) {
                  if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {                
                     var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
                     var key;
                     for(key in outputVariables) {
                        if(outputVariables[key].name === "myOutput") {
                        }
                     }
                  }
               };
               $Lightning.use("c:TKTflow", function() {
                  $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:flow", {"onstatuschange":statusChange},
                     "flowContainer",
                     function (component) {                    
                        component.startFlow("TKT_application_form");
                     }
                  );
               },);
            </script>
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
</apex:page>
```

This is the lightning component:

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp" implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess">
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:flow"/>
</aura:application>
```